# providing the right sequelize.js object to connect to the database(multi-tenant application)

Tags: mysql, express, mongoose, sequelize.js, mean-stack

**First some Background:**

We are trying to create a multi-tenant application, we thought of going on with using the [mean stack](http://mean.io) first and create multiple collection for each tenant (eg order_tenant1,order_tenant2 etc) then we went through some blogs that suggested against this approach, second we felt the need of transaction as a core requirement of our DB thus opened our self's to RDBMS lke mysql and mariaDB, we stumbled upon a [blog](http://web.archive.org/web/20120211232457/http://www.reachcrm.com/2010/03/11/multi-tenant-strategy-for-saas-using-mysql5)  which explained the  approach in a lot of detail which says to create views to get, update and insert data related to tenant and views parameter would be defined thorugh the connection string  as we are using node.js i found ORM for mysql [sequelizejs](http://sequelizejs.com/) which is quite good.

**The actual problem:**

As per my experience of the mean stack we define the mongo connection in the server.js file and the application establishes those connection at the application start and keeps them alive,
[image]
how can i have multiple sequelizejs (or for that matter and database connection )objects to connect to the database according to the user belonging to a particular tenant and provide the right object to the application to carry on with the business logic

1)should i create a new connection object on every request the application get and then close it after the request is processed ?

2)or is there  any better way to handle this in node, express or sequelizejs!?

Edited:
we have decided to use row-base approch containing the tenant_id as a column as said in the [blog above](http://web.archive.org/web/20120211232457/http://www.reachcrm.com/2010/03/11/multi-tenant-strategy-for-saas-using-mysql5), but i am struggling about how would i maintain dirrent connection object to the database through sequelizejs objects i.e id a user belonging to tenant id:1 sends a request to the application he need to be serverd  with an object say "db" which is a sequelize object to communicate with the database which is created using tenant id 1's details in its connection string, same for a user belonging  tenant id:2 it needs to be served with the same object i.e. "db" but it must be created using tenant id 2's details in its connection string as i want to maintain different connection string (database connection objects) for every tenant i have to serve.

Answer (score 0):

Multi-tenancy can be implemented as row-based, schema-based, or database-based. Other than that 2010 article, I think you will find few if any other recommendations for doing database-backed multi-tenancy. Systems were not designed to talk to tens or thousands of databases, and so things will keep failing on you. The basic thing you're trying to avoid is SQL injection attacks that reveal other user's data, but the proper way to avoid those is through sanitizing user inputs, which you need to do no matter what.

I highly recommend going with a normal row-based multi-tenancy approach as opposed to schema-based, as described in https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#multiple-schemas and in this original article: http://railscraft.tumblr.com/post/21403448184/multi-tenanting-ruby-on-rails-applications-on-heroku

**Updated:**

Your updated question still isn't clear about the difference between database-based and row-based multi-tenancy. You want to do row-based. Which means that you can setup a single Sequelize connection string exactly like the examples, since you'll only have a single database.

Then, your queries to the database will look like:

```
User.find({ userid: 538 }).complete(function(err, user) {
  console.log(user.values)
})
```

The multi-tenancy is provided by the `userid` attribute. I would urge you to do a lot more reading about databases, ORM, and typical patterns before getting started. I think you will find an additional up front investment to pay dividends versus starting development when you don't fully understand how ORMs typically work.

Comment: I think i was not clear about the question i asked,i have updated my question please go through the "edited "section for more details